# iOS PKCS#7 how to decrypt P7M file ? have .pfx file now

Tags: ios, encryption, pkcs#7

as the title said.
I have the .pfx file and .p7m file ,how can I decrypt the it ? 
in github , I searched the code

https://github.com/zkrige/iOS-pkcs7-decrypt

but can't do it.

platform : iOS

Comment: oc,openssl,swift

Comment: We don't have the files nor the code, as it currently stands, we cannot answer it even if we wanted to. Please add details, such as test input files and what code you are trying to run. Note that SO is for *programming related questions only*.